# What could be the best way to test firebase cloud message which sends to thousands of device?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Our stack:
backend: flask + nginx
frontend: android, ios
firebase cloud messagng for push message

We often discover bugs after fcm-related feature update. users report the bug with angry face :( We know that is not so good in terms of user experience. we need a way to catch the bug before we release it to actual product. first, let me give an example.

For instance, a user(named Fred) post a article, other users who subscribing fred should receive a notification message but after the release, we found that users who are using iphone are not receiving push message. (android was fine)

we couldn’t find the bug because back then we tested with a few android device which our developers have.

after that, we bought an iphone test machine but we don’t think that will suffice. we are desperated to expand our test coverage.

we are looking for a way to build a virtual test environment which simulates thousands of device receives push messages. so that we could test without sendng message to actual user.

currently looking firebase test lab. but I appreciate any Insights.

Comment: This is pretty much a duplicate question that has been asked several times before. Follow the link provided and look into TestFlight from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Android is you cannot test app with every Android device because there are thousands of variants. Probably the good idea to follow is to get the device of each manufacturer and test on it.

Mainly the problem occurs with Chinese brands like Xiaomi, Oppo, etc. Devices of these manufacturers have customs restrictions. With Apple devices there is not an issue they have a fixed set of devices, you can order these devices run automation tests on them.

Bam you are done. But you have to be careful with android. Firebase test lab is a good solution but it can be expensive.